# Two "global"/application layouts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Rails and I wonder if it is possible to have two different application layouts? I want the public interface of my website to appear different then what the admins see. So all the public actions will be rendered inside one application layout, while all admin actions is rendered in another one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can determine which layout to use with a `before_filter` in your application_controller.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  # other implementation

  layout :determine_layout

  def determine_layout
    current_user.admin? ? "admin" : "application"
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  layout Proc.new { |controller| controller.signed_in? ? 'admin' : 'application' }
end
```